# How to get XAML hot reload working on Uno Platform?

Tags: c#, .net-core, uno-platform

I've started a new Uno Platform project with the `dotnet new unoapp` template and have run into issues with hot reload  - where XAML/C# changes are meant to be reflected in the application without requiring a rebuild and a restart.

I am coding on VS Code in Linux if that is any help. I have the Uno Platform extension installed, but I am not getting code completion hints when typing XAML (which is a different problem I'm not asking about - but which may be helpful to know if it indicates the extension does not work and this is the reason for the lack of hot reload).

Some logs are below.

`dotnet --info` logs:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.400
 Commit:    7771abd614

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     pop
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk/6.0.400/

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.108 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk]
  6.0.400 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.28 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

`uno-check` logs:

```
 Uno Platform Check v1.5.3.0 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
This tool will check your Uno Platform development environment.
If problems are detected, it will offer the option to try and fix them for you, 
or suggest a way to fix them yourself.
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⏳ Synchronizing configuration... ok
⏳ Scheduling appointments... ok

 .NET SDK Checkup...
  – 6.0.108 - /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk/6.0.108
  – 6.0.400 - /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk/6.0.400

 .NET SDK - Workload Deduplication Checkup...

 GTK3+ Checkup...

 .NET SDK - Workloads (6.0.400-rtm.22364.21) Checkup...
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

✔ Congratulations, everything looks great!

Press Enter to finish...
```

Console logs when running WASM instead of GTK:

```
fail: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.RemoteControlClient[0]
      Failed to get remote control server port from the IDE for endpoint 192.168.1.16. dotnet.js line 1 > eval:1:9
fail: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.RemoteControlClient[0]
      Failed to get remote control server port from the IDE for endpoint [fe80::2a60:daed:fec3:e7dc]. dotnet.js line 1 > eval:1:9
fail: Uno.UI.RemoteControl.RemoteControlClient[0]
      Failed to get any remote control server endpoint from the IDE.
```

I'm not sure how I can fix this error, but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is a long shot- but what firewall are you using?  I am using the windows firewall- and quite often when I update VS, I get a prompt to allow xamarin broker on the firewall.  I am not sure it is your issue- but it may be blocked.

Comment: @Jt5 My operating system (Pop OS, a Linux distro) doesn't come with a firewall, so I don't think that's it, but I appreciate your intent to help. I think I will just leave it for now (only learning Uno for hobby stuff). Thanks for your help!